# Prevent Duplicate Entries On A Pivot / Linking Table in MySQL (with PHP / PDO)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, many-to-many

I currently have a many-to-many linking/pivot table called `boards_images` in MySQL that holds two columns, namely a `board_id` column and an `image_id` column, which are both foreign keys from a `boards` table and an `images` table respectively.

When a user adds an image to a board MySQL currently just adds the appropriate values with a simple `INSERT` statement via PHP / PDO:

```
// $boardId and $imageId are values taken from input elements on the submitting form.

$sql = "INSERT INTO boards_images (board_id, image_id) 
VALUES (:board_id, :image_id)";
";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute([
    ':board_id' => $boardId
    ':image_id' => $imageId
]);
```

However, this `INSERT` statement clearly doesn't prevent images that are already on a board from being added multiple times again to the same board.

What is the best way to prevent this? Will I need to make an initial `SELECT` statement with the `board_id` value? Such as:

```
SELECT * FROM boards_images where board_id = :board_id
```

...and then run a check against this? And if so how do I check for the duplicate `image_id` value? I perhaps naively thought changing the `INSERT` to `INSERT IGNORE` would be what I needed, but it seems not.

Answer (score 3):

You need an UNIQUE composite index on the PIVOT table. This index should include both `board_id` and `image_id` fields.

```
ALTER TABLE `pivot` ADD UNIQUE `my_unique_index` ( `board_id`, `image_id`) ;
```

Then in your INSERT SQL just do this to silently deal with duplicates:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO boards_images (board_id, image_id) VALUES (:board_id, :image_id) ON DUPLICATE board_id = :board_id ;";
```

If you try to insert a duplicates, the UNIQUE INDEX will prevent to insert the duplicate record and the ON DUPLICATES clause will silently discard the INSERT without generating an error.

Comment: I've only just got around to trying this. Unfortunately it does throw an error, namely `Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'board_id = ?' at line 2` The two columns in the `boards_images` table are both foreign keys, which may be causing the issue